# Setting 'Sensitivity Label' and 'Enable Update Of Links' using XSSFWorkbook in Java

Tags: java, excel

I am creating an excel spreadsheet using the XSSFWorkbook jar

The spreadsheet has links that retrieve data from an external file, and when opening the file I get the following dialog box
[Dialog Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NEe0.png)

Is there any way I can make the external links 'protected' so I dont get the dialog.

Also, my organisation insists on setting a Sensitivity Label on all Excel spreadsheets.
[Sensitivity Label Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjnUm.png)

Is there any way I can set this?

Thanks in advance

Neil

Not able to try, as need help to identify a solution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.